# Get user input from qml to c++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm trying to get user input from **qml TextField** to **c++**, but it only works if **text property value** is hardcoded *(const value)*.

### c++

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

QObject *rootObject = engine.rootObjects().first();
QObject *serverField1 = rootObject->findChild<QObject*>("serverField1");

qDebug() << serverField1->property("text"); //Here I expect to get user input
```

### Qml

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: applicationWindow
    visible: true
    width: 300
    height: 550

    TextField {
        id: serverField1
        objectName: "serverField1"
        width: 200
        height: 110
//    text: "hardcoded value" //If text is const value, qDebug will get data from this property
    }
}
```

Comment: @eyllanesc, I need to get text that person write in this TextField, but when I try to get text properety I not get person input, I get text properety that I code in qml firstly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are asking for the text of the `TextField` when the window is displayed so what you will get is the text you have initially set, what you should do is get it every time it changes. I think that you have some class that will handle some processing with that data, that class will be called `Backend`, it must inherit from `QObject` so that it can have a qproperty and embed an object of that class to QML through `setContextProperty`, so every time it changes the text in `QML` will also change the text in the `Backend` class object.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QQmlProperty>

#include <QDebug>

class Backend: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString text READ text WRITE setText NOTIFY textChanged)
public:
    QString text() const{
        return mText;
    }
   void setText(const QString &text){
        if(text == mText)
            return;
        mText = text;
        emit textChanged(mText);
    }
signals:
    void textChanged(const QString & text);
private:
    QString mText;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    Backend backend;

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("backend", &backend);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    // test

    QObject::connect(&backend, &Backend::textChanged, [](const QString & text){
        qDebug() << text;
    });
    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    TextField {
        id: serverField1
        x: 15
        y: 46
        width: 120
        height: 45
        topPadding: 8
        font.pointSize: 14
        bottomPadding: 16
        placeholderText: "Server Ip"
        renderType: Text.QtRendering
        onTextChanged: backend.text = text
    }
}
```

<sub>You can find the complete code in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/50609108).</sub>